# Can Spring Vault support Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, spring-vault

From the [Spring Vault official site](https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault#overview), it supports HashiCorp’s Vault, and there are some examples with HashiCorp’s Vault.

Does it support Azure Keyvault natively?

From [the azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault), springboot starter is

```
<groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can the spring vault integrated with the Azure Key Vault?
If it can, how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

There is no official document for spring vault to integrated with Azure Key Vault.

From this spring boot official document it only say about HashiCorp’s vault integration.There is no other cloud platform other than HashiCorp’s vault integrate with spring cloud vault.

> Spring Cloud Vault Config provides client-side support for
> externalized configuration in a distributed system. With HashiCorp’s
> Vault you have a central place to manage external secret properties
> for applications across all environments. Vault can manage static and
> dynamic secrets such as username/password for remote
> applications/resources and provide credentials for external services
> such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, Apache Cassandra, MongoDB, Consul, AWS and
> more.

But you can access the azure key vault using the access key in your spring boot application for that you can refer the same [***document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault)

***Reference : https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault#overview***